# Convert Table Creation from MSSQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Street1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Street2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What would the equivalent PostgreSQL table creation script look like, based off of the previous MSSQL create script? Looking for an approach/resource that can guide me on converting MSSQL schema to PostgreSQL ...

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Phil's answer is correct. As you also asked for "*for an approach*", here is a very short description to convert Microsoft T-SQL:

- always end your statements with a `;` (in general: replace `GO` with `;`) - and no, the `;` does **not** go in front of the `with` keyword for a common table expression
- remove the non-standard square bracket "quoting" `[..]` (I highly recommend to **never** use quoted identifiers). Details about the identifier syntax [are in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)
- identity columns map to `serial` or `bigserial` in Postgres. That implies the data type `integer` or `bigint` so you only need the keyword `serial`. For details [see the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)
- there is no `nvarchar` in Postgres. All character columns use the same character set.
- other data types to convert (incomplete!):

  ```
  SQL Server         Postgres
  ---------------------------
  image              bytea
  binary             bytea
  varbinary(max)     bytea
  varchar(max)       text
  nvarchar(max)      text
  text               text
  ntext              text
  bit                boolean
  datetime           timestamp
  smalldatetime      timestamp
  timestamp          no equivalent
  uniqueidentifier   uuid 
  xml                xml
  ```
- there are not clustered indexes so remove the `clustered` attribute
- the whole `with` part defines physical properties of the table that are not relevant in Postgres
- the `dbo` schema "maps" to the `public` schema in Postgres. It is somewhat uncommon prefix tables with `public` though unless you changed your schema search path (there is also no need to use the schema prefix for your own functions as it is required in SQL Server)

Some things to watch out for:

- string comparison is case **sensitive** in Postgres. `where name = 'Arthur'` will return something different than `where name = 'arthur'`. Search this site, there are plenty of questions regarding this.
- the "poor man's regex" syntax of SQL Server's LIKE (e.g. `like '[0-9]'`) does not work in Postgres. You need to use the regex operator.
- date handling [is a bit different](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)
- Postgres is much more picky about correct data types and value literals. `where varchar_column = 2` fails in Postgres even if there are only numbers in that column
- In Postgres you can insert multiple `null` values into a unique index on a nullable column. The following fails in SQL Server but works in Postgres

  ```
  create table foo (col1 integer, col2 integer);
  create unique index idx_foo on foo (col1, col2);
  insert into foo (col1, col2) values (1, null);
  insert into foo (col1, col2) values (1, null);
  ```

---

**This list is by no means complete!** There is a *lot* more to look out when converting from one DBMS to another.

Comment: You could create a schema called "dbo" if you like this SQL Server schema.

Comment: just log back into this account and @vivek is correct; this is gold. thanks for the detail and feedback. i feel more confident now to continue with the migration. just worried now about gaps in my `serial` columns, as there were some deletions in the applicable MSSQL table that may not map now to their foreign keys in other tables :/ ... guessing that's going to manual work, right? you know of a way to maintain referential integrity during the migration process, aside from manually updating foreign key columns?

Comment: @culturalanomoly: just import the existing values into your Postgres database and then adjust the sequences to the current max. value (using `setval('sequence_name')` don't worry about the gaps

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks again! i'd tip you if i could ... have a gittip account or something akin to it?

Comment: A slightly more complete list for the type mapping can be found here: http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-postgresql

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses(
    Id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId int NULL,
    City varchar(50) NULL,
    State varchar(50) NULL,
    CountryCode varchar(50) NULL,
    PostalCode varchar(50) NULL,
    Street1 varchar(50) NULL,
    Street2 varchar(50) NULL
);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b76b6